# VBA Select file from dialog box (only specific file extensions)

Tags: vba, openfiledialog, solidworks

I am trying to write a code where when clicking a commandbutton - it shows a dialog box browser for files and the user can only select ".xlsx" file. WHat I have so far is:

```
Sub CommandButton_Browse_Click()
    
    Call Set_FileBrowser
    
    'TextBox_OutputDirectory
    If Not SelectedFile Is Nothing Then
        Me.TextBox_InputDirectory.Text = SelectedFile.Self.Path
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Set_FileBrowser()
    
    Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set SelectedFile = shellApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a file", 16384)
    
End Sub
```

It shows the file browser, but it has no filters regarding file format. What's teh correct approach and solution to this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.filters

Comment: If you are trying to get it working NOT inside an office application, then you will want to use VBScript, not VBA.

Comment: Yeah, the tricky part is that it's in SOLIDWORKS API which is not excel but it still uses VBA

Comment: Oh then my answer was premature 

Comment: https://help.solidworks.com/2016/english/api/sldworksapi/open_file_example_vb.htm

Comment: @braX I am not trying to open a SOLIDWORKS file, In fact I need a user to select a .xlsx file so I an use it's hyperlink and do magic. My code works as I want BUT I need to restrict the user to be able to select only the "xlsx" and "xlsm" files, you know?

Comment: You just change the filter then. It demonstrates how to use a filter in a solidworks open dialog, which is what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: SOLDIWORKS dialog if it's a proper dialog box won't have any otehr file formats but ones compatibel with SOLDIWORKS i.e. ".sldprt", ".sldasm" etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution for Solidworks

Adapted from the [documentation](https://help.solidworks.com/2023/english/api/sldworksapi/open_file_example_vb.htm?verRedirect=1):

```vb
Function SelectXlFile() as String
    Dim DialogTitle As String
    Dim InitialFileName As String
    Dim FileFilter As String
    Dim OpenOptions As Long
    Dim ConfigName As String
    Dim DisplayName As String
    Dim fileDisplayState As String

    'Example for a single file type:
    DialogTitle = "Select an Excel file."
    FileFilter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"

    'Example for multiple file types:
    'DialogTitle = "Select an Excel or Word file."
    'FileFilter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xlsm)|*.xlsx; *xlsm|Word Files (*.docx)|*.docx"

    SelectXlFile = Application.SldWorks.GetOpenFileName2(DialogTitle, InitialFileName, _
                       FileFilter, OpenOptions, ConfigName, DisplayName, fileDisplayState)
End Function

Sub CommandButton_Browse_Click()
    'TextBox_OutputDirectory
    Me.TextBox_InputDirectory.Text = SelectXlFile()
End Sub
```

#### Solution for MS-Office:

```vb
Function SelectXlFile() as String
    SelectXlFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                       FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", _
                       Title:="Select a file.", _
                       MultiSelect:=False)
End Function

Sub CommandButton_Browse_Click()
    'TextBox_OutputDirectory
    Me.TextBox_InputDirectory.Text = SelectXlFile()
End Sub
```

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I just read your comment on your original question about needing it to work in SOLIDWORKS API. Yes this does require the `Application` object to provide the method `.GetOpenFilename`

Comment: Edited answer returns "Automation error element not found"

Comment: Hmm, I changed i again, maybe it works now?

Comment: Now it's a type mismatch on the same line when setting FullXlWBName. If it's trying to filter by the actual filters when you click file / open -  it's impossible because there is no excel file format allowed. And again I am not trying to open teh file, I just need the user to select a file so I can get it's full path so I can programmatically open it in teh background as needed by the program

Comment: Made a stupid mistake now it should work...

Comment: Same "Type mismatch"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249809/discussion-between-eduards-and-gwd).

Comment: @GWD maybe click on the Feedback link on that Solidworks help page and tell them?

Comment: @braX I now noticed that I looked at the wrong documentation. The `VB.NET` Integer is equal to a `VBA` Long (32-bit) ‍♂️ Sorry for the confusion I caused

Comment: Then what was the issue the OP was having?

Comment: I don't know, I think your links were enough to solve the problem